# Access is denied (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a problem where I create a user in MySQL, and I try to access localhost with it on the web. However, it just throws at me:

Access denied for user 'default_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Here is the user creation:

```
    mysql> CREATE USER default_user;
           Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

    mysql> GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT ON test.*
        -> TO 'default_user'@'localhost'
        -> IDENTIFIED BY 'bacon';
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

And the PHP:

```
    <?php

DEFINE('DB_USER', 'default_user');
DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD', 'bacon');
DEFINE('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE('DB_NAME', 'test');

$dbconnect = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
OR die('Connection aborted' . mysqli_connect_error());

 ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `CREATE USER 'default_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'bacon';`

Comment: Is your mysql server running from localhost?

Comment: Daan, sorry, but it didn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Grzegors, yes it is.

Comment: @SojaTunes did you execute `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after `GRANT...` ?

Comment: Yes, I did, but still no luck.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone for the help! I simply fixed it by backing up my data, and reinstalling MySQL through Homebrew then restarted to make sure all processes were killed!